# create trigger withour using the the mysql statment

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I tried to create a trigger on my webhosting, then I got the error that I dont have the super privilege to do that.  Then the support told me that they cannot give me that super privilege on the server, only VPS hosting and very expensive hosting can do that.

So im trying to figure out how to do a "kind of" trigger when insert, update or delete with out using the mysql statment, just using php.

Any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the trigger to do?

Comment: which version of mysql your host run?

Comment: I just want to do mostly the same a trigger does, lets say when an update on my table happens, trigger an insert into another table with the value that was changed, new value and old value.  The version is MySQL Databases 6.